# How to find matching elements in an array and append them in two new different arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, foreach

I'm trying find matching elements and append them into two different `arrays`. The data is coming from the backend so i don't know what the teams are but the data contains all the markets. I would like to find matching elements e.g get markets that belong to `West ham` and `Burnley` then append these into 2 different `arrays`.

This is an example array that contains all the markets

```
let marketItems = ["West Ham Total Goals - Over/Under 2.5", "Burnley Total Goals - Over/Under 1.5",
                        "Burnley Total Goals - Over/Under 2.5", "West Ham Total Goals - Over/Under 0.5"]
```

Arrays i wanna append matching markets into

```
var homeTeamMarkets: [Market] = []
var awayTeamMarkets: [Market] = []
```

Comment: `homeTeamMarkets = marketItems.filter{ $0.hasPrefix("West Ham")}`?

Comment: @Larme that is just an example of the data that comes from the backend, i don't know the team name which i what i'm trying to achieve without explicitly using the team name. It could be different teams

Comment: And how do you know "homeTeam" or "awayTeam" then?

Comment: @sk123  Post your `Market` structure. Also, does the data from the backed come in this format: `"West Ham Total Goals - Over/Under 2.5"`? That's not going to be easy to parse. If the backend is serving JSON, show us some sample JSON.

Comment: @Rob bad highlighted person, else, quicky done : `let teams = Array(Set(marketItems.compactMap({ $0.components(separatedBy: " Total Goals - ").first })))` to know all the teams, then filter according to... ? But a struct  (ie custom model) would be good.

Answer (score 1):

The following will create this dictionary:

`["Burnley": [1.5, 2.5], "West Ham": [2.5, 0.5]]`

You haven’t indicated that there’s any way to tell which one is “home” and which is “away”. If you can't, a `Dictionary` is the best you can do.

```swift
public extension Dictionary {
  /// Group key-value pairs by their keys.
  ///
  /// - Parameter pairs: Either `Swift.KeyValuePairs<Key, Self.Value.Element>`
  ///   or a `Sequence` with the same element type as that.
  /// - Returns: `[ KeyValuePairs.Key: [KeyValuePairs.Value] ]`
  init<Value, KeyValuePairs: Sequence>(grouping pairs: KeyValuePairs)
  where
    KeyValuePairs.Element == (key: Key, value: Value),
    Self.Value == [Value]
  {
    self =
      Dictionary<Key, [KeyValuePairs.Element]>(grouping: pairs, by: \.key)
      .mapValues { $0.map(\.value) }
  }

  /// Group key-value pairs by their keys.
  ///
  /// - Parameter pairs: Like `Swift.KeyValuePairs<Key, Self.Value.Element>`,
  ///   but with unlabeled elements.
  /// - Returns: `[ KeyValuePairs.Key: [KeyValuePairs.Value] ]`
  init<Value, KeyValuePairs: Sequence>(grouping pairs: KeyValuePairs)
  where
    KeyValuePairs.Element == (Key, Value),
    Self.Value == [Value]
  {
    self.init( grouping: pairs.map { (key: $0, value: $1) } )
  }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation

extension Market {
  enum DecodingError: Error {
    case invalidFormat(String)
    case notANumber(String)
  }

  static func decode(_ strings: [String]) throws -> [ String: [Double] ] {
    .init(
      grouping: try strings.map {
        let nameAndBet = $0.components(separatedBy: " Total Goals - Over/Under ")

        guard nameAndBet.count == 2
        else { throw DecodingError.invalidFormat($0) }

        let betString = nameAndBet[1]
        guard let bet = Double(betString)
        else { throw Market.DecodingError.notANumber(betString) }

        return (teamName: nameAndBet[0], bet)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
try Market.decode(marketItems)
```